# How to fill stroke colours on based of percentages in circle in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am creating a circle and divided into four parts. stroke colours should be filled by based on given percentage.

```
    func showCircle() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+0.2) { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
         
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
           let total: Int = 4
           let width: CGFloat = 10.0
           let reducer: CGFloat = 0.0 // add gape b/w segments if reducer > 0
           let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2),
                                         radius: self.frame.size.width / 2,
                                         startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * Double.pi),
                                         endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * Double.pi),
                                         clockwise: true)
      
        // these are the percentages 
        let percentages = [0.20, 0.15, 0.35, 0.30]
           
           for i in 1...total {
            
            let percentage = CGFloat(percentages[i - 1] )

            let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
               circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
            
            switch i-1 {
            case 0:
                circleShape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.431372549, green: 0.231372549, blue: 0.631372549, alpha: 1)
                
            case 1:
                circleShape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6784313725, green: 0.568627451, blue: 0.7882352941, alpha: 1)
                
            case 2:
                circleShape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8470588235, green: 0.7960784314, blue: 0.8980392157, alpha: 1)
                
            case 3:
                circleShape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.937254902, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
            default:
                circleShape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            }
               circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
               circleShape.lineWidth = width
               circleShape.strokeStart = CGFloat(CGFloat(i - 1) * percentage) + reducer
               circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(CGFloat(i) * percentage) - reducer
            self.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
           }
        }
}
```

Wrong result:- these colours should be filled based on percentage.
[image: this is not correct output]

Expected result:- we can see in this picture colours are filled properly based on percentages.
[image: expected result]

Comment: I couldn't find a relation between the values of `percentage` and colours in the expected images. Is `percentage` only example values?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with calculating start and end.
Try in this way, initialise `strokeStart` to 0 outside the loop, and calculate `strokeEnd` like `let strokeEnd = strokeStart + percentage - reducer` then set `circleShape.strokeStart = strokeStart
        circleShape.strokeEnd = strokeEnd`. Finally at the end of the loop set `strokeStart = strokeEnd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that the strokeStart and strokeEnd should be from 0 to 1 and increase as the index increases.

This is gonna work:

```
    // these are the percentages
    let percentages = [0.20, 0.15, 0.35, 0.30]
    
    for i in 1...total {
        let prevPercentage: Double = percentages.prefix(i - 1).reduce(0, +)
        let percentage = percentages[i - 1]
        
        let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
        circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
        
        switch i-1 {
        case 0:
            circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            
        case 1:
            circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            
        case 2:
            circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            
        case 3:
            circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        default:
            circleShape.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        }
        circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleShape.lineWidth = width
        circleShape.strokeStart = CGFloat(prevPercentage)
        circleShape.strokeEnd = CGFloat(prevPercentage + percentage)
        view.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this solution is exactly that for what I was looking.